# Global maximum for $\log x - \frac{x}{\pi(x)}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

$\log x - \frac{x}{\pi(x)}$ hits a global maximum at $x=24,137$ with a value of $1.11196\dots$

[image]

Is there any documentation about this anywhere? I couldn't find any. Apologies if there is and it is easy to find :)

Comment: Rosser and Schoenfeld give a proof that this maximum is < 3/2.  I suspect that their proof can be improved. http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.ijm/1255631807

Comment: @MatthewConroy, Thanks for the link :)